# find xaml text with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, xaml

How could I find all `TextBlocks` in xaml files which contains `Style` parameter using search in `Microsoft Visual Studio`. Is there any regexp possible to be used here? Here is an example of block:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.boom, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
        Foreground="{StaticResource gray}"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        Style="{StaticResource sdfsdf}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Visibility="{Binding ErrorOccured,Converter={StaticResource ToVisibilityConverter},ConverterParameter=true}"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the need to find? If you elaborate the purpose the we can suggests a shorter way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're in an editor, the usual warnings about using regex to parse xml can be relaxed (only a bit)...

This will work:

```
(?s)<TextBlock(?:(?!/>).)*?\bStyle=.*?/>
```

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/fG7bI0).

- The trick is to make sure we don't get past the closing tag and end up matching more text than we want.
- If there are nested `<tags>`, this will fail

**Explanation**

- `(?s)` activates `DOTALL` mode, allowing the dot to match across lines
- `<TextBlock` matches literal characters
- The non-capturing group `(?:(?!/>).)` matches one character, as long as it is not followed by `/>` (this is to avoid jumping out of the present tag)
- `*?` allows the type of character just mentioned to mach lazily, zero or more times, up to...
- `\bStyle=` the literal `Style=`, with a `\b` on the left to ensure that `Style` is not embedded in `MyStyle`
- `.*?` lazily matches characters up to...
- the closing `/>`

Comment: FYI, added detailed explanation.